# localStorage in rails list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, view, local-storage

I'm kind of a railsnoob, and I'd like to make a view with lists using localStorage.
I have a Products-view, in which you should click a button to add it to the Lists-view.
The Lists-view contains a list of products that are in the cart, product that are already bought, and products recently viewed (for the last one I'd like to use sessionStorage).
However, I get stuck going from the Products-view to the Lists-controller and the Lists-view.
here are my codesnippets.

to send an item to the right list, I've created this form in products.show.html.erb

```
  Add to:
  <%= form_tag("/lists/index", :method => "get") do %>
<input type="radio" name="listcat" value="cart">Put in Cart
<input type="radio" name="listcat" value="bought">I've already Bought this
<%= hidden_field_tag :product_id %>
<input type="submit" value= "Go!">
  <% end %>
```

in lists_controller.rb

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    if params[:listcat] == "bought"
      @listbought = Product.where("product_id = ?", params[:product_id])
    end

    if params[:listcat] == "cart"
      @listcart = Product.where("product_id = ?", params[:product_id])
    end

  end
end
```

and then I get stuck in lists.view.html.erb, because I don't know how to call on the instance variables (I now try to declare it in the header through erb), and how to put them in the list (some iteration using the key value using localStorage?). The list right now is "Cart", because when that works, the "Bought"-list will be the same, and the "recently viewed" is going to use a different approach, but that'll come eventually.

```
<head>
  <title>Lists</title>
  <% cart = @listcart %>
  <script>
    localStorage.getItem("cart");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Lists<h1>
  <h3>Cart</h3>
  <ul id="cart">
    <li></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: general curiosity - shouldn't `@listbought = Product.where("product_id = ?", params[:**P**roduct_id])` be `@listbought = Product.where("product_id = ?", params[:**p**roduct_id])`

Comment: you're right, thanks. Just a typo though, in my code it's all lowercase.